# Casting To Subtype Within a LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I've reviewed other answers to similar questions but can't find exactly what I want.  I have a dictionary of type Superclass that can store  instances of either of 2 subclasses.  I need to be able to access a member of one of the subclasses.  I can't figure out how to cast in the LINQ query to the subclass to access it.  here's what I have.

```
class VirtualFabric
{  Dictionary<string, SANSwitch} MemberSwitches = new Dictionary<string, SANSwitch>();    

class SANSwitch
{  
     string SwitchWWN {get; set; }
     Dictionary<int, VirtualFabric> VirtualFabrics = new Dictionary<int, VirtualFabric>();
}

class CiscoSwitch : SanSwitch {}
class BrocadeSwitch : SanSwitch
{
 public Dictionary<int, string> VirtualWWNList = new Dictionary<int, string>();

  public bool HasWWN(string wwn)
     {
        if (wwn.StartsWith("55")) { return this.VirtualWWNList.Values.Contains(wwn); }
        else { return this.SwitchWWPN.Contains(wwn); }
     }    
}
```

So the MemberSwitches in a VirtualFabric can store instances of either CiscoSwitch or BrocadeSwitch.  I'm trying to do this:

```
List<SwitchPort> isls = this.ISLs.SelectMany(p => p.Value.Where(i => i is FCPort)).ToList();

        // set up the ISLs
        // if the remote switch port list already contains a port, then that switch log has been processed 
        // so do nothing

 foreach (SwitchPort p in isls)
{   
    var bs = this.VirtualFabricList.SelectMany(t =>   t.Value.MemberSwitches.Values.Where
(s => s.Value.HasWWN(p.RemoteSwitchWWPN)));  

// do something with any results
} // foreach
```

The SelectMany is not compiling because HasWWN() is defined in BrocadeSwitch and not SANSwitch.  I could move it to SANSwitch but don't want to.  I could also get all the switches in MemberSwitches of type Brocade or iterate over and declare them as Brocade and then search that list, but I'm wondering if there's a way to cast within the LINQ statement.  I have seen examples of Select of a certain type, but that's not what I want.

Comment: If you can cast one class, you can use `Select` to cast all into new list

Comment: I know.  I was hoping to avoid that and possibly learn something.

Comment: [Enumerable.OfType<TResult> Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class which derives another class:

```
public class Class1 { }

public class Class2 : Class1 {
   public List<Class2> Twos { get { return new List<Class2>(); } }
}
```

Here is how to cast:

```
var c1 = new Class2();
var c2 = new Class2();
var l = new List<Class2> { c1, c2 };
var ints = l.SelectMany( x => x.Twos ).Cast<Class1>();
```

Or just cast the enumerator instead of casting each object like this:

```
var ints = l.SelectMany( x => x.Twos ) as IEnumerable<Class1>;
```

Since `Class2` derives `Class1`, you can do the cast. However, if you try and cast from `Class1` to `Class2` it will fail because `Class2` is more specific.

**EDIT**

You have this lambda:

```
var bs = this.VirtualFabricList.SelectMany(t =>   t.Value.MemberSwitches.Values.Where
(s => s.Value.HasWWN(p.RemoteSwitchWWPN)));
```

`MemberSwithches.Values` will return `SANSwitch` and then you are trying to call `s.Value.HasWWN` method but `CiscoSwitch` does not have `HasWWN` method. You cannot do that. You need to do this:

```
var bs = this.VirtualFabricList.SelectMany( t => t.Value.MemberSwitches.Values
   .Where( s => s.Value is BrodcadeSwitch ) ).Cast<BrodcadeSwitch>()
   .Where( s => s.HasWWN( p.RemoteSwitchWWPN ) );
```

Comment: ok.  using your example I'm trying to cast from Class2 (the derived class) to Class1.  So I will have to instead do the cast before the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to describe the type VirtualFabricList.

From you linq statement I gather that a VirtualFabricList is not a sequence of VirtualFabric objects, because each "t" in your VirtualFabricList has a property `Value`, a property not in your VirtualFabric class.

However, from the rest of your linq I gather that each t.Value is a VirtualFabric. Furthermore each t.Value has a property MemberSwitches which is a dictionary containing SANSwitch objects.

You want only some objects from this dictionary: only those SANSwitches in the dictionary that are BrocadeSwitch objects. And not even all BrocadeSwitches, but only those where HasWwn(...) returns true.

Your problem is that you check all elements in the dictionary of SANSwitches for HasWWN, while you only can only check the BrocadeSwitch ones. For this you can use [Enumerable.OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

In small steps:

```
IEnumerable<VirtualFabric> virtualFabrics = this.VirtualFabricList
    .Select(t => t.Value>);
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, SANSwitch>> dictionaries = virtualFabrics
    .Select(fabric => fabric.MemberSwitches);
IEnumerable<SanSwitch> sanSwitches = dictionaries
    .SelectMany(dictionary => dictionary.Values);
```

Note: if my guesses about your VirtualFacbricList are incorrect, use your own statements to get a sequence of SanSwitch objects. From this sequence you can get the BrocadeSwitches:

```
IEnumerable<SanSwitch> sanSwitches = ...
IEnumerable<BrocadeSwitch> brocadeSwitches = sanSwitches.OfType<BrocadeSwitch>();
IEnumerable<BrocadeSwitch> switchesWithWWN = brocadeSwitches
    .Select(brocadeSwitch => brocadeSwitch.HasWWN(...)
```

So the key feature is **Enumerable.OfType**

These small steps help you to check that each linq statement contains the items you expect. It won't slow down your process, because of deferred execution those statements will not be executed until your ToList().

Of course, if readability and debug-ability is not the highest on your priority list you can put these statements into one big linq statement.